# Remote Debugging for .NET WPF Application via Visual Studio 2008 Remote Debugger?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, debugging, remote-debugging

Remote Debugging for .NET WPF Application via Visual Studio 2008 Remote Debugger can this be done ? I see native only in the options ? Any help please...

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can. You run the remote debugger on the client PC, you run VS2008 on your dev PC. You select "attach to process" and enter the remote server name in the filter box. You should then be able to select your application from the process list. (You obviously need to make sure that the list is showing managed process - this can be changed via an option on the dialog)

The fact it is a WPF app makes no difference, you can remote debug any .net app with visual studio as long as you have the correct source code and matching symbol files.